# Given that the relation that aRb if and only if the smallest element of a is is equal to the smallest element in b?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, multisets

X is the set of all nonempty subsets of the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. 
a,b are elements of X.

a) Find the number of elements in the equivalence class [{2,6,7}]?

```
My solution:

1) Choose 2 to be in the set, 1 way
2) 2^9, which includes any number to be in the set except 2

Ans: 1 * 2^9 = 512
```

b) Find the number of four-element sets, which are member of the equivalence class [{2,6,7}]?

```
My solution:

1) Choose 2 to be in the set, 1 way
2) Choose 2^3, which includes any 3 number to be in the set except 2

Ans: 1 * 2^3 = 8
```

Comment: For $a$, what's the domain, otherwise the answer is infinite.

Comment: Note that your current method allows sets such as $(1,2)$ and $(1,2,5)$,, which are not in the equivalence class $[\lbrace(2,6,7\rbrace)]$.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, $a$ and $b$ are only considered to be in the same equivalence class if they have the same smallest element.

If this is the case, then for a) the answer would be $2^8=256$ since 1 cannot be in any of the equivalent elements.

For b) the answer would be ${8\choose 3}=56$ since you can have any 3 of the numbers from 3-10.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that your relation is an equivalence relation.

The equivalence class of $[\{ 2,6,7\}]$ is the set of all subsets of $\{1,...,10 \}$ having least element $2$. Now, we say the following: Suppose $2$ is an element of our set, then any number from $3$ to $10$  can be in the equivalence class of this set. That is to say, there are $3^8=256$ elements.

As for $b$, we are now looking  at $4$ element subsets. $2$ has to be one of the elements, that is fixed. The other $3$ elements can be chosen out of the elements $\{3,...,10 \}$ (we can't have $1$ as then that would be the least element). That is, we have to choose $3$ numbers out of $8$ without replacement, the ways of doing that is $\binom{8}{3} = 56$. Hence your answer will be $56$.

When we are choosing elements without replacement, we do not exponentiate. Hence answers like $2^3$ would not be likely in the case of $b$.

Comment: In part a) you have removed the subsets that include 1, but shouldn't you also remove the subsets that don't include 2?

Comment: Correct. I have done just that. Thank you, and $+1$.

Comment: What is the difference between 2^8 and 8C2?

Comment: @00111000 Do you mean as far as how to calcucate them, or when you would use each one?

Comment: @browngreen When you would use each one, b/c both questions seem very similar but you use 2 methods of calculating subsets.

Comment: $8\choose 3$ is used when you want to choose *exactly* 3 of the 8 elements.  $2^8$ is used when you can choose *any amount* of the 8 elements (therefore each element has two possibilities, either it is in the group or not).